# Incorrect histogram display

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have tried to plot two sets of data in a histogram!
the data sets looks like this:

```
>>> df = load_diffae()
>>> print(df.shape)
(360000, 5)
>>> dfn = load_diffne()
>>> print(dfn.shape)
(360000, 5)
```

Both have 360000 rows

However, if you look at the histogram, it looks like the new data set has significantly more rows (shown on the Y axis) than the old data set. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from Extract_elevation import *

def load_diffae():
    df = dfl
    return df 

def load_diffd():
    dfn = dfld
    return dfn 

def Plot_show_eu(df,dfd, dfn):

    x = dfe['O18ad']
    z = dfne['O18nd']
    bins = np.linspace(-50, 1, 40)
    bins = 'auto'
    plt.hist(x, bins, alpha=0.65, label='alt')
    plt.hist(z, bins, alpha=0.65, label='new')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Comment: You are using `bins='auto'`, which means that `hist` will calculate the bin size automatically. Your green plot has clearly wider bins than the blue one, so it is not at all clear, visually, that the blue one has more points than the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bins are chosen differently, so more values enter each bin for larger bins and the plot appears "bigger".